# Understanding the example of RNN package in R

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

In the [RNN package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rnn), there is an example to use RNN to train summation of two numbers.

I tried to look up in Google, but did not find a good resource to explain how can we use RNN to train this kind of task.

Could you give me some references for this task.

The input of the task is:

`X1  X2  Y` (with `Y = X1 + X2`)

You give `X1`, `X2` and `Y` to RNN, and it can learn how to predict `Y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I based this problem on this video by Geoffrey Hinton:

[A toy example of training an RNN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0ZtWWa43gk&index=32&list=PLPWgVABcUWuXb-zQiKyqRD91nETdSE5fW)

Basically, in order to do binary addition in bit-by-by steps, in order to learn how to carry a 1, a feed-forward neural network needs roughly 10 neurons.

A recurrent neural network can do this using only 3 neurons.

That is what this example demonstrates.